# Pontiac Vibe remote not working

Tags: pontiac, locks, door, keyless-entry, vibe

My 2010 Pontiac Vibe's doors no longer work using the remote. They work fine from inside the car, but won't function with the dongle. I replaced the battery in the dongle with no joy. The back hatch door seems to still work with the remote, but nothing else.

Is there a central point of failure such as relays that would effect all the doors except the back hatch door?

Comment: Not sure if you car functions like this, but some remotes need to be re-synced with the car after a reset, which for me included pushing keypad buttons on the driver's door.

Comment: he said he can still open the hatch.